# xslt transformation, get data from referenced xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new here, I need help with a xslt transformation, in the source xml exists a reference to another xml, how can i access the data from external xml?, some like  `<xsl:value-of select="NewsItemRef/externaldata"/>`, help me please.

xml containing reference to other xml.

```
<NewsComponent>
        <NewsLines>
          <HeadLine>some description</HeadLine>
        </NewsLines>
        <NewsItemRef NewsItem="ref_external.xml"/>
      </NewsComponent>
```

i want to get data from external xml referenced

Comment: Can you post an example of the XML you have and the result you want to see?

Comment: And where is the other XML file?

Comment: the other xml is in te same folder

Comment: Then my solution should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open external XML documents using the `document()` method:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document(NewsItemRef/externaldata)"/>
```

Comment: in this way can i access the external xml data as local?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: "NewsItemRef" contains a reference to other xml, in this way I can access the information of external xml?

Comment: @Carlos are you talking about accessing a remote xml that lies in another server?

Comment: No, the referenced xml is in the same folder

Comment: thanks for your help, i use `<xsl:variable name="ref" select="document(@NewsItem)"/>`

Comment: well, you can obviously also use `<xsl:value-of select="document(@NewsItem)/some/element"/>`